# Plesk vs rails3 assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, plesk

I took over a clumsily-installed Rails app. Its assets are broke. Chrome Audit returns:

```
> Leverage browser caching

The following resources are missing a cache expiration.
Resources that do not specify an expiration may not be cached by browsers:

jquery-1.8.3.js
jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js
rails.js
application.js
jquery.ui.base.css
jquery.ui.theme.css

...etc.
```

This obviously churns our network. Wat do? Where in Rails-land, or Plesk's vhost.conf file, does one add a line of configuration so the correct HTTP headers go out?

Please don't tell me "just rebuild the assets" - the rebuild is slightly broken.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at Andre Spannig's page if you like tweak the web server configuration for your current domain only: [Plesk 10 and vhost.conf](http://www.andre-spannig.com/2012/06/plesk-10-vhost-conf).
This helped me once on a different issue.

There may be a better way through Rails but I am not aware of one right now.

Comment: tx no - I ran /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain ... and the bug remains. Yes I added this snip to vhost.conf:   <FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png|js|css)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </FilesMatch> (and this edit system SUCKS!)

Comment: Adding <IfModule mod_expires.c> / ExpiresActive On / ExpiresDefault A1209600 ... , then rebuilding the conf, then apachectl restart, all fixed it. Tx!